# Counting words that start with capital letter on python

Tags: python, regex, csv

### **im a newbie here. Im kinda working on a program that counts words that starts with capital letter, per line inside a csv file using python. I used regex but i think it doesnt work. Here is the sample code that i made but unfortunately it doesnt give the output that i want. hope you could help me.

**

```
             import re
             line_details = []
             result = []
             count = 0
             total_lines = 0
             class CapitalW(): #F8 Word that starts with capital letter count   
             fh = open(r'20items.csv', "r", encoding = "ISO-8859-1").read()
             #next(fh)
             for line in fh.split("n"):
               total_lines += 1
                   for line in re.findall('[A-Z]+[a-z]+$', fh): 
                      count+=1
                      line_details.append("Line %d has %d Words that start with capital letter" % 
                      (total_lines, count))
             for line in line_details:
             result7 = line
             print (result7)
```

**- result should be as follows:

Line 1 has 2 Words that start with capital letter

Line 2 has 5 Words that start with capital letter

Line 3 has 1 Words that start with capital letter

Line 4 has 10 Words that start with capital letter**

Comment: What does it mean to be _kinda working_?

Comment: You should fix the indentation.

Comment: Thank you. I will fix it

Comment: Okay, so what is different about your actual result vs. the desired result? (Keep in mind that we cannot see your input file.) Do you notice a pattern to the differences? Can you think of where that pattern might be coming from?

Comment: there was no output before but i fixed the indention just as Armali said and it showed some progress. But it doesnt read every line. only the first line.

Comment: If you fixed the "indention", you should update your post. How should one spot remaining errors otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

In the regex you doens't need the $ character beacause [A-Z]+[a-z]+$ matches only if there is one word in the line. So [A-Z]+[a-z]+ instead. 
The other, is, that I see from the encoding, that you maybe use characters what are not between a-z for example é. So you maybe have to add these also to the pattern. [A-ZÉÖ]+[a-zéö]+ and add all the other special characters.

Comment: Also you have to be precise with the tabs in the second for loop.

Comment: yes i fixed the tabs. it showed 1 output. Im still trying to figure out why it cant read per line in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a fixed indentation and in addition to matebende's answer, these are the required further corrections:

- `for line in fh.split("n"):` is supposed to be `for line in fh.split("\n"):`.
- The initialization `count = 0` has to be inside this `for` loop.
- The `fh` in `for line in re.findall('[A-Z]+[a-z]+$', fh):` is wrong and has to be `line`.